# automatic focus after modfying an item in a listview

Tags: c#

I have a `list-view` on my windows form, and there are approx. 200 items in it. My query is, if i find some item has some mistake in there spelling or something else. So when i am selecting that item and then modify back in the `list-view` then i want to focus on that particular item.

right now i am doing this:-

```
    listView1.Items[this.listView1.Items.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
 //i know that this code is for focusing on the very last item.
```

Please help me.

thanks in adv. :)

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: i dnt have any problem with my code. i just want to focus on that particular item which i modify in the listview after click update button.

Comment: What is your "particular item"? Do you have the index of the item, or the `ListViewItem` object?

Comment: yes i have the index number of dat particular item.

Comment: suppose there is an item in the listview "Podim", when i review all the items then i found dat the spelling of dat particular item is wrong, it should be "Podium". so i click on the item and paste it in the text box. after editing the spelling i click the modify button. now i want the focus after modifying dat item.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
listView1.SelectedItems[0].EnsureVisible();
```

if you want to bring the first selected item to the view.

Or if you want to *select* a particular item:

```
listView1.Items[i].Selected = true;
```

or

```
listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(i);
```

That depends on what are trying to do exactly.

EDIT:

If you want to focus the list view after modifying item, you can write:

```
void btnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // change the item...

    // focus the list view
    listView1.Select();
}
```